# Comment box appear on clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm extremely new to front end web development, and I was wondering if there is anyway I can have a small text box appear on clicking a link, which disappears when I submit the form. (I want something like what Facebook has currently for the birthday wishes, where you click on the persons name, a small comment box opens up 'on top', and lets u post a wish on the persons wall from the main page itself).

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best will be to use a framework like [jQuery Dialog UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default). The documentation is big and there are a lot of samples available.

For instance, create a div element with your input text and bound his creation to the button you want:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="dialog">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <a href="#">Open dialog</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $('a').click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answerer is assuming you're using jQuery.  If that's true, I would look at [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).  It's **much** slimmer and simpler than jQuery UI

Comment: @iman - no problem.  I hope jQuery UI works out well for you :)

Answer (score 1):

basic example in plain javascript to get you started

```
<form id="mainForm">
    <a id="clickme" href="javascript:;">click me</a>
    <input id="submitme" type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    var mainForm = document.getElementById("mainForm"),
        textBox = document.createElement("input");

    textBox.id="tmpTextBox";
    textBox.type="text";

    document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function () {
         mainForm.appendChild(textBox);
    }

    document.getElementById("submitme").onclick = function () {
        mainForm.removeChild(textBox);
    }
</script>
```